# Why didn't it seem darker outside with 66% of the sun covered by the moon?

Tags: solar-eclipse

I live in Austin, TX where the eclipse on August 21, 2017 reached its maximum point with ~66% of the sun covered by the moon.

**Why didn't it seem any darker than a normal time with 0% eclipse?**

Comment: Should be merged with https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/22230/how-much-of-the-sun-needs-to-be-blocked-in-order-to-see-a-noticeable-drop-in-bri

Comment: Your eyes are designed to let you see in varying levels of illumination. If the day is a bit duller your eyes adapt.

Comment: Human eye intensity response is not linear, it is more like logarithmic